# Unexpected result calculating points of an ellipse

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to make a line from the center of an ellipse to a random point of the border. Basically, my code is a copy-paste of some js code that I did some time ago. I was using a canvas and vanilla js.

My code:

```
var o;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  o = ellipseGetRandomPoint(250,250,200,300);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  stroke("black");
  fill("#333333");
  ellipse(250,250,300,400);

  stroke("red")
  line(250,250,o.pointX, o.pointY);
  console.log(o);
  fill("#999999");
  stroke(0);
  ellipse(250,250,200,300);
}

function ellipseGetRandomPoint(centerX, centerY, radiusX, radiusY) {
    let o = {};
    r = Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
    pointX = centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(r*Math.PI / 180);
    pointY = centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(r*Math.PI / 180);
    o.pointX = Math.floor(pointX);
    o.pointY = Math.floor(pointY);
    o.r = r;
    return o;
}
```

The problem is that there is some part of the line that it's outside the ellipse, and I don't really know why, because the parametric equations of the parabola seem to be ok and also a really similar version of this code is working on my other js program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd and forth parameter of the [`ellipse()`](https://processing.org/reference/ellipseMode_.html) are the width and the height of the ellipse rather than the semi axis.

So the parameters for `ellipseGetRandomPoint` have to be `150, 200` rather than `200, 300`:

<s>`o = ellipseGetRandomPoint(250,250,200,300);`</s>

```js
o = ellipseGetRandomPoint(250,250,150,200);
```

See the example:

```js
var angle = 0;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
    let o = ellipseGetRandomPoint(250,250,150,200);
    angle += 1;

    background(220);
    stroke("black");
    fill("#333333");

    ellipse(250,250,300,400);

    stroke("red")
    line(250,250,o.pointX, o.pointY);
    console.log(o);
    fill("#999999");
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(250,250,200,300);
}

function ellipseGetRandomPoint(centerX, centerY, radiusX, radiusY) {
    let o = {};
    r = Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
    r = angle;
    pointX = centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(r*Math.PI / 180);
    pointY = centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(r*Math.PI / 180);
    o.pointX = Math.floor(pointX);
    o.pointY = Math.floor(pointY);
    o.r = r;
    return o;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```